# Collapse Menu - Não recolhe após selecionar um item

Tags: css, menu, collapse

Em um site One Page, implementei este Collapse Menu

```
    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-sm bg-nav navbar-dark fixed-top">
  <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">
    <img class="logo" src="images/logo.jpg" alt="logo">
  </a>
  <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapsibleNavbar">
    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
  </button>
  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="collapsibleNavbar">
    <ul class="navbar-nav">
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#section2">Quem Somos</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#section3">Nossos Serviços</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#section4">Nossos Clientes</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#section5">Contatos</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>
```

CSS e JS são estes:

```
  <head>
 <title>Meu Site.</title>
 <link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" href="images/favicon.ico">
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<style>
body {height: 100%;width: 100%;}
html {height: 100%;width: 100%;}
form{height: 100%;padding-bottom: 250px;}
.bg-nav{background-color:#077877!important}

  @media (max-width:667px) {
    img.logo{width: auto; height: 40px;}
    .desfault-section{padding-top: 65px;padding-bottom: 20px;}
  }
  @media (min-width:668px) {
    img.logo{width: auto; height: 60px;}
    .desfault-section{padding-top: 90px;padding-bottom: 20px;}
  }
</style>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

Quando é exibido em tela de celular, o menu abre ao clicar nas 3 barras, porém, 
ao escolher um item do menu, o mesmo deveria recolher automaticamente sem ter que clicar nas 3 barras e, isto não está acontecendo.

Alguém me dá uma luz?

Comment: Se a âncora for para a mesma página deve ser necessário inserir o evento em cada botão

Comment: Amigo edite a sua pergunta e coloque o seu CSS e o Script desse Menu, sem ele não é possível te dar uma resposta com exatidão

Comment: Sam, este post que você indicou resolveu o problema. Muito Grato.